# set Height for Text

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

I want to increase the height for the text but the width does not change, is there any way to help me ???
Because The height of the Linear width has not changed but I want TextView to contain all 15 characters and it must have a text size of 28px

this is my XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="158px"
android:layout_height="31px"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/black"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/d2_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO"
    android:textSize="28px"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:fontFamily="@font/arial_narrow"
    android:textColor="#FFFF00"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:padding="-10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
 />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Send xml layout please

Comment: You need to change height but width not to change?

Comment: yes, I need to change height but width not change

Comment: @stupidDeveloper Please add an image of what currently you're getting and what you want. explain in brief your problem

Comment: At least android:layout_height="wrap_content"